# Trying to extract column reference from ME23N

Tags: sap-gui

cntlMEALV_GRID_CONTROL_MMHIPO/shellcont/shell").selectColumn "XBLNR"

I'm trying to extract this into excel.

I was only able to extract row count using watch but not sure how extract this using excel

Any code or sample or help will be appreciated thanks.

[image: ME23N Reference column]

Comment: Your screenshot shows a [GuiGridView](https://help.sap.com/viewer/product/sap_gui_for_windows/760.01/en-US?q=guigridview) object. Please try some of the methods and explain what result you obtained if you need further assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use getcellValue to cast to excel.

```
Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
Set SAPApp = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
Set SAPCon = SAPApp.Children(0)
Set session = SAPCon.Children(0)

MyGrid = "cntlMEALV_GRID_CONTROL_MMHIPO/shellcont/shell"
iRows = session.findById(MyGrid).RowCount()
'Fill excel sheet   
Do While i < iRows  
       
    Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = session.findById(MyGrid).getcellValue(i, "XBLNR")
    i = i + 1
Loop
```

Comment: Thank you this is correct also I used Csonor Varga youtube video on GUIGRID was also very helpful.